# sublime text: how to make vertical guide lines little thicker

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using sublime text.

I am using the following in the settings to show indent lines:

```
"indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_normal",
        "draw_active"
    ],
```

And also changed the color using the following in the color theme files:

```
<key>guide</key>
<string>#000000</string>
<key>activeGuide</key>
<string>#c60519</string>
```

But now i want to make the indent lines thicker. Presently i am able to show them and change color by the above settings.

SO how to make indent lines thicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to configure this; the default width is hard coded in the rendering code so the only modifiable options are the colors to use. Note tha the default configuration specifically mentions that there should be an option in the scheme to change the width, although no such option is known to exist.

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/2136) requesting that this feature be added in a future build.